# Angular http post number array

Tags: angular, api, rest, post, http-post

I am trying to post an array of integers to a REST API from Angular frontend (to be added to a SQL database).

Here is what my array look like:

```js
number[] =  [1, 13, 41];
```

Here is my add function:

```js
addTrades(id: number, trades: number[]) {
  return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.contractorAPIMainUrl}` + 'ContractorTrades?id=' + id, trades)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("Http Post Response: " + data);
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    this.alertService.clear();
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      this.errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
    } else {
      this.errorMsg = this.getServerErrorMessage(error);
    }
    this.alertService.error(this.errorMsg);
    return throwError(this.errorMsg);
  });
}
```

Below are the values I tried sending instead of `trades`, but all failed:

```js
// didn't work => trades, {trades}, JSON.stringify(trades), '[7,8]', '{[7,8]}'
```

I also tried without using any as below, but didn't work either.

```js
return this.http.post(`${environment.contractorAPIMainUrl}` + 'ContractorTrades?id=' + id, trades)
  .subscribe(data => { console.log("Http Post Response: " + data);
```

API works fine with Swagger as expected and the values have been added to the database as expected.

Please see the screenshots below.

**Image1**

[image]

**Image2**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it?

EDITS:================================================================

[Please see the Postman details. This works fine and adds the values to the database. So, now the only problem is it's not working with the Angular front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jivik.png)

- I am not passing any headers
- IMPORTANT : When I debug locally (both front-end and API) I have noticed that the function "PostContractorTrade" of the API is not getting hit (other functions like GET, DELETE works fine). But with Postman, it get hit and works fine. So, I think it's something to do with the Angular POST function.

API POST Function.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ContractorTrade>> PostContractorTrade(int id, int[] trades)
    {
        try
        {
            string retVal = "";
            List<ContractorTrade> list = new List<ContractorTrade>();
            for (int i = 0; i < trades.Length; i++)
            {
                var contractorTrade = new ContractorTrade();
                contractorTrade.ContractorId = id;
                contractorTrade.TradeId = trades[i];
                list.Add(contractorTrade);
                retVal += trades[i] + ",";
            }
            _context.ContractorTrades.AddRange(list);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Content("Added Entities : " + retVal.TrimEnd(','));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content("Post Exception from API : " + ex.Message + ex.InnerException + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

[And the auto-generated headers by Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZIY4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be a problem related to serialization.
Please provide information about the request that angular is making.
Also, provide information about the error that ASP is throwing.

Comment: When I try it with Postman, it gives the error below, but it Adds the records to the database. 
The header contains invalid values at index 0: '7,8'   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser`1.ParseValue(StringSegment value, Int32& index)
   at Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(StringSegment input)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase.Content(String content, String contentType)
   at ContractorAPI.Controllers.ContractorTradesController.PostContractorTrade(Int32 id, Int32[] trades) in

Comment: Can you share a picture of the whole request body that you make with postman? Are your headers okay? Angular code looks fine, there is something going on with the BE I suspect.

Comment: Please see my edits at the bottom of the original question

Comment: @Jay the way you have written your API function it will not work. You need to add [FromBody] attribute to your trades, otherwise it will try to parse them from the query params. 
However, you mentioned the API method is not getting hit from angular. What error are you getting?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me Aleks. This has now become a big issue as everything I tried didn't work. Yes, I did try with [FromBody] in the API function, but didn't work either(sorry for not posting as an update). This looks so normal and something straight forward. Maybe that's why not many people care to help. But the fact is it's not working here. I have posted all the code needed and desperate for a solution. Please let me know if you need anything else to help.

Comment: No problem. I have had such problems myself, and I do know how tricky they can be.
I need the error you are getting from angular when calling your API. Make sure you are actually sending a request, which has the right parameters. I.E you can have the wrong URL, and so on.
I went ahead and dug some old code out: https://pastebin.com/eLzpRTD3
This currently works for me. Note that the List<T> is not a problem, it works fine with [] as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an array using params

```
let params = new HttpParams();
const numbers = [7, 8];
params.append('numberArray', JSON.stringify(numbers);
this.http.post(url, { params });
```

Comment: I tried with the hardcoded value like this. 
`code`return this.http.post(`${environment.contractorAPIMainUrl}` + 'ContractorTrades?id=' + id, '[{7},{8}]').subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Http Post Response: " + data);`code`
Now it's giving a different error message: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: If you can share the request that the backend needs it's easy to answer

Comment: Please see my edits at the bottom of the original question

Comment: You can pass an array using params